# logging module for python reports incorrect timezone under cygwin

Tags: python, logging, timezone

I am running python script that uses logging module under cygwin on Windows 7. The `date` command reports correct time:

```
$ date
Tue, Aug 14, 2012  2:47:49 PM
```

However, the python script is five hours off:

```
2012-08-14 19:39:06,438: Done!
```

I don't do anything fancy when I configure logging for the script:

```
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)-15s: %(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)
```

Can someone tell me what is going on and how I can fix it?

Comment: can you try adding `datefmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%s'` to the `logging.basicConfig` call?

Comment: I'm using Cygwin 1.7.16 and it works correctly. Date and the logging module both return the timestamp.

Comment: Looks like it's using UTC? Maybe you need to set the `TZ` environment variable.

Comment: Nowadays I tend to use native applications instead of Cygwin. Take a look at [Gow](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki/) and [ConEmu](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/).

Comment: Thank you, I will try suggestions in the comments, and report back tomorrow. @Paulo I would prefer to solve the problem under cygwin, before looking at the alternatives.

Comment: @mgilson I get an exception with this format: ValueError: Invalid format string.

Comment: @MarkRansom $ echo $TZ -- seems to return a correct value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to unset the environment "TZ" in your python script prior to any importing the date/time modules.  It is set by cygwin but not understood by Windows:

```
if os.getenv("TZ"):
    os.unsetenv("TZ")
```

Comment: Interesting, @Yun-Chen Sung. This does NOT work when I do it from the script. If I do unset and export TZ from bash before I run it, the correct time is displayed. Do you know why this code does not work in Cygwin?

Comment: @Nikita: If I do this before I import `time` `time.timezone` gives me the windows timezone.  If I do this after I import `time` I get the wrong timezone.  I assume `time` checks `$TZ` once on import.

Comment: This solution did not work for me (unsetting TZ from inside Python was "too late" and I got the incorrect GMT behavior) but I found that running "unset TZ" in the bash shell PRIOR to calling Python worked.  One way to automate the fix is to stick "unset TZ" in your .bash_profile.  I also recommend dbl-checking at runtime that datetime.datetime.now() != datetime.datetime.utcnow() by an appropriate (hours) margin because this behavior seems to depend on the exact version of Cygwin.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that if `TZ` environment variable is set, Python in Cygwin will operate in GMT (UTC) timezone.  This is true even when `TZ` is set to the same timezone as the Windows box!

As a workaround you can call `unset TZ` in the bash shell prior to calling Python and then Python will use the Windows timezone.  For me, deleting the ENV variable inside Python did not work and it needed to happen prior to starting Python (even if deleting `os.environ['TZ']` was as early as possible in the Python process before importing any time-related modules, possibly because one has to import `os` and maybe that triggers the Cygwin/Python "bug" whereby the timezone becomes UTC?).

One can automate the fix by adding `unset TZ` to the .bash_profile file (in `/home/<user>` which is a subdir of the location where Cygwin is installed).