# Git Commit is using a wrong timezone

Tags: bash, git, datetime, cygwin, git-commit

Normally I use two PCs, say: `PC1` and `PC2`.

On both of them I'm using `CygWin` on `Windows 10`.

They had the same configuration.

On `PC1` I was trying to do some adjustments on how to display the date and time when doing:

```
$ git log
```

I was trying multiple `bash` and `git` commands.

In the past and also currently on `PC2` when I do:

```
$ date
```

I get the following:

```
Tue Sep 25 16:17:34 CDT 2018
```

but on `PC1` (the wrong one), with the same command, I get:

```
Tue, Sep 25, 2018 16:17:34
```

where you can see that the `TimeZone` indicator is not showing up.

Also, now on `PC1`, when I do a commit and then list the history with: `$ git log`, dates are like:

```
Date:   Tue Sep 25 22:58:42 2018 +0100
```

where it should be:

```
Date:   Tue Sep 25 16:58:42 2018 -0500
```

because my current timezone is: `CDT` (`America/Chicago`) (`-05:00`)

Any idea on how to solve this?

Thanks!

**[EDIT 1]**

Responding to suggestion from `@Johan` below where he said:

**--- begin of comment ---**

You need to set the `git log --date` to `local`.

```
git config --global log.date local
```

**--- end of comment ---**

I just tried that and now the date that shows up on my last commit doesn't have the `TimeZone` indicator. Using the same time reference as before it would be:

```
Date:   Tue Sep 25 22:58:42 2018
```

I need to get the `TimeZone` indicator on the commit list.

**[EDIT 2]**

Responding to suggestion from `@Johan` below where he said:

**--- begin of comment ---**

You need to set the `git log --date` to `default`.

```
git config --global log.date default
```

**--- end of comment ---**

I just tried that and now and I get again:

```
Date:   Tue Sep 25 22:58:42 2018 +0100
```

even trying new commits.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `git log --date` to `default`.

```
git config --global log.date default
```

---

**Source**: [git: timezone and timestamp format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651644/git-timezone-and-timestamp-format)

Comment: I answered on `[Edit 1]` above.

Comment: Sorry @DavidSmith I misunderstood your question. I thought you wanted to get rid of the timezone and show it in local time. My bad. The `default` setting should solve it. I have updated my answer to it. Please try it and tell if it solves it.

Comment: thank you @Johan, unfortunatelly didn't. I answered on `[Edit 2]` above.

Comment: Okay, there's some trial and error :) You can also define your own timezone format, in your case it would look like: `format:"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y %z"`.
Otherwise I would guess there's some underlying issue with the timezone. [This was the only thing](http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/tzset.html) I could find on timezones for Cygwin

Comment: By the way, you can test the different settings by using `git log --date=<desired setting>` instead of changing the settings for each try

Comment: This might also be of interest: [Emacs and Git show wrong time on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16884170/emacs-and-git-show-wrong-time-on-windows)

Answer (score 2):

I don’t think this will address the root issue on your system, but it will certainly help with git’s commit dates. Git uses an environment variable called `TZ` to set the timezone (for any command, not only commit), so you can set an alias for it in your shell:

```
alias git='TZ=CDT /usr/bin/git'
```

Comment: I think this is the most robust solution for "set and forget", unfortunately. If you're concerned about Git being invoked without the environment variable set, you can write a pre-commit hook that will block such commits.

Comment: For me `TZ=CDT` did not work but `TZ=America/Chicago` did!

Answer (score 0):

Check if the issue persists when:

- using a regular `CMD`
- setting a simplified `PATH`

That is:

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GH=C:\path\to\git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
```

Note that with that setup, you benefit from 200+ Linux-like commands without even opening a bash (again, from a regular CMD session): you can type `ls -alrth` or `grep` or ... (directly from the CMD, no bash)

Since the date used in a commit is directly from the system, if `time /T` returns the proper hour ([including DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time)), you won't have any issue with a `git log` date.