# Github commit graph showing incorrect commit dates

Tags: git, github, graph, timezone, commit

I normally commit in PST timezone. I am currently in another country which is 16 hours ahead UCT+9.

It is currently October 11th ~22:00 in my home country. Here it is October 12th ~14:00.

My laptop correctly displays the new timezone and so does my terminal when I run `date +%z`.

When I pushed a commit today, it appeared under October 11th on my commit graph instead of October 12th. How can I fix this?

Comment: Might this thread be helpful?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52507279/git-commit-is-using-a-wrong-timezone

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651644/git-timezone-and-timestamp-format. In short - use ``--date` in log for getting unified timestamp